# nothing was returned from render but can't be fixed

Tags: react-native

I don't know what I did wrong in this function, I thought I had a return but I don't think it's being considered, and when I change the closing brackets or parenthesis it shows an error :/
Can someone help me?

```
function PopSheet() {
      
      let popupRef = React.createRef()
      const sheet =() => {
       
       
        const onShowPopup =()=> {
          popupRef.show()
        }
        const onClosePopup =()=> {
          popupRef.close()
        }
       
        return (
        <SafeAreaView style ={styles.container}>
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onShowPopup}>
  
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <BottomPopup 
        title="Demo Popup"
        ref ={(target) => popupRef =target}/>
        onTouchOutside={onClosePopup}
       </SafeAreaView>
       
        
       );
        }
      };
```

Comment: Sheet is a function that's not called anywhere. Popsheet doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You need to use the `render` function which is responsible for rendering or display the JSX element into your app.</s>

```
render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
          onPress={onShowPopup}></TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <BottomPopup title="Demo Popup" ref={target => (popupRef = target)} />
        onTouchOutside={onClosePopup}
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! but it didn't work :/ 
It showed that render () is missing ';' which doesn't make since..

Comment: @MahDi sorry I got it wrong. You're using a functional component, right? So you need to use useRef hook instead createRef, and can you please share the whole program to check for results and error. Your BottomPopup component too.